# C Function Multiple Definition Error but declared once?

Tags: c, list, exception, header

I've been starting a small project in C with the purpose to create a library of my own to use single linked lists without hassle.

I use three files for the project: the main file (main.c), a header (with a header guard, sll.h) and it's declaration + definition file "sll.c"

However, I ran into three errors when trying to compile the C program in this state:

FILE 1 main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sll.h"

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

FILE 2 sll.h

```
#ifndef SLL_H_11_14_2019
#define SLL_H_11_14_2019

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
} Node;

typedef struct List {
    int size;
    Node * head;
} List;

List createSLList();

void appendSLList(List list);

int searchSLList(List list, int key);

void popSLList(List list);

void removekeySLList(List list, int key);

void removeSLList(List list, int index);

void deleteList(List list);

#endif
```

FILE 3 sll.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sll.h"
/* Contains source code for sll.h. Should not be used standalone without sll.h to avoid duplication issues. */
/* This library provides definition for functions to create and manipulate a single linked list. */

List createSLList(){
    List list;
    list.size = 0;
    list.head = NULL;

    return list;
}

void appendSLList(List list);

int searchSLList(List list, int key);

void popSLList(List list);

void removekeySLList(List list, int key);

void removeSLList(List list, int index);

void deleteList(List list);
```

The errors:

```
        sll.o           In function `createSLList':
7       sll.c           multiple definition of `createSLList'
        main.o          sll.c:17: first defined here
        collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
25      Makefile.win    recipe for target 'sll.exe' failed
```

I'm honestly baffled; createSLList is only defined once. I looked and (obviously) stdio.h and stdlib.h should not be throwing any errors, considering they've got header guards of their own, so what's the catch?

Edit: Compiled with GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Debug
with Language Standard C99 & all warnings enabled + making them fatal errors.

Edit2: In hindsight, I did #include "sll.h". Edited and posted the new code, yet the error remains. Posted makefile.win too.

```
//makefile.win
# Project: single linked list
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

CPP      = g++.exe -D__DEBUG__
CC       = gcc.exe -D__DEBUG__
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = main.o sll.o
LINKOBJ  = main.o sll.o
LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc -g3
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"
BIN      = sll.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -g3
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -g3
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS) //ERROR IS HERE

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c main.c -o main.o $(CFLAGS)

sll.o: sll.c
    $(CC) -c sll.c -o sll.o $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: Include a definition in multiple compilations, get multiple definitions. What's the hard-to-understand part here?

Comment: why are you including headers multiple times `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Could you please show us a Makefile contents? It seems like your createSLList is being compiled twice (in sll.c -> sll.o, main.c (including sll.c code via sll.h) -> main.o), so the Makefile could be helpful in finding a solution.

Comment: @roottraveller Because I need them in sll.c . It does not matter regardless, they have header guards, this should not cause a problem.

Comment: @jthill If you're so kind to elaborate please?

Comment: @g_elef, for the original version of the sources posted, it would work if you just remove ssl.o from Makefile. For the current version, it should work as is, you just need to add functions implementations in sll.c (leave it empty, like: void appendSLList(List list) {};)

Comment: @g_elef, actually it works even without implementations (just the warning thrown), tested in in Visual Studio.

Comment: @HenadziMatuts Upon doing seemingly random things, and deleting all object files and the makefile, and restarting the IDE, it has compiled without any error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Dev-C++ initially compiled my program as a C++ program, even though I had "picked" C as the default language. As a result, this had destructive consequences.

For anyone facing similar problems, what worked for me was deleting all the files created by the compiler and restarting the IDE. Please note that you should manually set what compiler to use under "project settings".